# How to get current Unix timestamp in Inno Setup?

Tags: unix, installation, inno-setup, unix-timestamp

Please let me know How to get current Unix timestamp in Inno Setup?

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, please try  http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ . (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: @Shelter - Yes it is, InnoSetup has built in Pascal script and that is the only way you might be able to get the unit timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`time()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) function from the C runtime library, which has the following return value:

> Return the time as seconds elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970, or
>   -1 in the case of an error.

which is exactly what the [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is.

Now it's a simple matter of importing that function into Inno Setup scripting. Since the scripting environment doesn't know pointers the parameter (which luckily need not point to a valid buffer, see the linked documentation) is given as integer and you **must** pass a 0 for it:

```
function Time(ATimerPtr: integer): integer; external '_time32@msvcrt.dll cdecl';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox(Format('unix timestamp: %d', [Time(0)]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: _time32 is available from Vista, if you want support for WinXP use time@msvcrt.dll